# How to change the color of dots in whole document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

For example if I have a lot of mcq questions like this: 
 1. something ..... something. 
 2. sometihngg ..... something. 
They have the same number of dots, How can I change the color of dots into red  in the whole document automatically with find and replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Press `Ctrl`-`H` to open Find and Replace. Click the "More >>" box if it is not already expanded.
2. In the "Find what" box,
   enter the number of dots. In your example, that would be 5 dots:
   `.....`
3. Click in the "Replace with" box to give it focus, then click the "Format" menu and choose "Font":
   [image]
4. And from there you can set the font color:
   [image]
5. Click "Ok" and "Replace All", and it should change the color of all instances of 5 dots in a row to red.

Comment: How can I do that with the entire row that has 5 dots?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: It is enough to specify formatting in "Replace with" field, no need for repeating the search string.